# write python 2d list containing list to parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having a 2d python list, I'm trying to write this into a flat parquet file

```
dcm = [['00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, [2.635471698,99.99]],
    ['000076a0-b770-11e7-af3c-618a1ae0aeae', 4, [1.966436237,999.9]],
    ['00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, [2.635471698,9999]],
    ['00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, [2.635471698,999.9]],
    ['000071e0-b813-11ea-a1aa-61e10098e853', 3, [2.378136118,99.99]]
   ]

        print("the schema of  :",type(dcm))
        print("the schema of 0 :", type(dcm[0][0]))
        print("the schema of 1 :", type(dcm[0][1]))
        print("the schema of 2 :", type(dcm[0][2]))

<class 'list'>
the schema of  : <class 'list'>
the schema of 0 : <class 'str'>
the schema of 1 : <class 'numpy.int64'>
the schema of 2 : <class 'list'>
```

I tried converting it to pandas dataframe and write it to parquet like below
print(type(dcm)) #<class 'list'>

```
<class 'list'>
```

Tried writing using pyspark

```
       act_schema = StructType([
            StructField('col1', StringType(), True),
            StructField('col2', StringType(), True),
            StructField('metrics', ArrayType(FloatType()), True)
        ])

final_output = spark.createDataFrame(data=dcm, schema= act_schema)
n = len(final_output.select(final_output.metrics).first()[0]) # Sometime the last column can have more than one value

dataframeToWrite = final_output.select(final_output.col1, final_output.col2,                        *(col('metrics').getItem(i).alias(f'col{i}') for i in range(n)))

dataframeToWrite.write.parquet('/user/loc', mode="overwrite")


Error:

     *(col('metrics').getItem(i).alias(f'col{i}') for i in range(n)))
TypeError: col() missing 1 required positional argument: 'strg'
```

expected output

```
'00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, 2.635471698,99.99
'000076a0-b770-11e7-af3c-618a1ae0aeae', 4, 1.966436237,999.9
 '00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, 2.635471698,9999
'00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, 2.635471698,999.9
'000071e0-b813-11ea-a1aa-61e10098e853', 3, 2.378136118,99.99
```

Comment: as for me it needs only `for-loop` to get `[2.635471698, 99.99]` and put it back as two values. And later you can save it even using module `CSV` (or you can use `pandas`) because expected output looks like `csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand problem but for me it needs only `for`-loop to get last element from row (and remove it) and append two values separatelly to row.

```
dcm = [
    ['00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, [2.635471698,99.99]],
    ['000076a0-b770-11e7-af3c-618a1ae0aeae', 4, [1.966436237,999.9]],
    ['00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, [2.635471698,9999]],
    ['00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, [2.635471698,999.9]],
    ['000071e0-b813-11ea-a1aa-61e10098e853', 3, [2.378136118,99.99]]
]

for row in dcm:
    item = row.pop(-1) # get last item and remove it from list
    row += item        # append every element from item separatelly
    #row.extend(item)  # append every element from item separatelly

print(dcm)
```

Result

```
[
 ['00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, 2.635471698, 99.99], 
 ['000076a0-b770-11e7-af3c-618a1ae0aeae', 4, 1.966436237, 999.9],  
 ['00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, 2.635471698, 9999], 
 ['00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, 2.635471698, 999.9], 
 ['000071e0-b813-11ea-a1aa-61e10098e853', 3, 2.378136118, 99.99]
]
```

---

Your output looks like `csv` so you could use standard module `csv` to write all at once.

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh, quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    writer.writerows(dcm)
```

And you can convert `csv` file into `parquet` file using `pyarrow` or `pandas`.

```
import pyarrow.csv
import pyarrow.parquet

table = pyarrow.csv.read_csv('output.csv')
#print(table.schema)
pyarrow.parquet.write_table(table, 'output-pyarrow.parquet')
```

OR you can convert `dcm` directly to `pandas.DataFrame` and then save it as `parquet` file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dcm, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'metric1', 'metric2'])
df.to_parquet('output-pandas.parquet')
```

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working example

```
import csv

dcm = [
    ['00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, [2.635471698,99.99]],
    ['000076a0-b770-11e7-af3c-618a1ae0aeae', 4, [1.966436237,999.9]],
    ['00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, [2.635471698,9999]],
    ['00004120-13e4-11eb-874d-637bf9657209', 2, [2.635471698,999.9]],
    ['000071e0-b813-11ea-a1aa-61e10098e853', 3, [2.378136118,99.99]]
]

for row in dcm:
    item = row.pop(-1)
    row += item

print('--- dcm ---')
print(dcm)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh) #, quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    writer.writerow(['col1', 'col2', 'metric1', 'metric2'])
    writer.writerows(dcm)

# --- pyarrow: from csv ---

import pyarrow.csv
import pyarrow.parquet

table = pyarrow.csv.read_csv('output.csv')
pyarrow.parquet.write_table(table, 'output-pyarrow-csv.parquet')

print('--- schema ---')
print(table.schema)

# --- pandas: from csv ---

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
df.to_parquet('output-pandas-csv.parquet')

# --- pandas: from data/list ---

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dcm, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'metric1', 'metric2'])
df.to_parquet('output-pandas-data.parquet')

# --- pyarrow: from data/dict ---

import pyarrow.csv
import pyarrow.parquet
import pyarrow as pa

schema = pa.schema({
        "col1"    : pa.string(),
        "col2"    : pa.int64(),
        "metric1" : pa.float64(),
        "metric2" : pa.float64(),
})

columns = {
    'col1': [],
    'col2': [],
    'metric1': [],
    'metric2': []
}

for row in dcm:
    columns['col1'].append(row[0])
    columns['col2'].append(row[1])
    columns['metric1'].append(row[2])
    columns['metric2'].append(row[3])

table = pyarrow.Table.from_pydict(columns, schema=schema)
pyarrow.parquet.write_table(table, 'output-pyarrow-data.parquet')

print('--- schema ---')
print(table.schema)
```

Comment: My input is not CSV, It's actually a output from numpy array, But your answer helped.